# Using the word, 'friendship' in a sentence

Tags: grammar-myths

Is it correct to say,
I have been in a friendship
I'm in a friendship

because I've always read and heard - I'm friends with or I have been friends with

Please explain

Also, if it's correct to say, I'm in a relationship then why does I'm in a friendship sound wrong to me?

Comment: The expression _in a relationship_ is a modern coinage, to allow for the fact that people have romantic/sexual unions without necessarily being engaged or married. There isn't a corresponding expression _in a friendship_ because there is no need for it - we just use the traditional _X is my friend_ or _we are friends_.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this clarification. I'm a communication coach and sometimes I do get such queries from the learners. Such questions leave me puzzled at times because I know that the sentence or the expression doesn't sound right, but I may not be able to find the reason. Thanks once again!